# How to load txt files into D3.JS

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to load a text (mydata.txt) file into d3.js. mydata.txt looks like this

name,   age,
Maria,  30,
Fred,   50,
Francis,    12

I used the follow code but I get this error at the console: "Unexpected value NaN parsing width attribute."

```
<script>
    //d3.txt("mydata.txt", function(data) {
    d3.csv("mydata.txt", function(data) {

    var canvas = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width",500)
                    .attr("height",500)

            canvas.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                        .append("rect")
                        .attr("width",function(d){return d.age*10;})
                        .attr("height",48)
                        .attr("y",function(d,i){return i*50;})
                        .attr("fill", "blue");


})  
</script>
```

Comment: try removing the spaces after the commas. most CSV parsers that i've encountered don't like that.

Comment: Two things 1. In your width function, console log the d before you return the function. Most likely the spaces are throwing your error. 2. Your csv should be in format: header (columns), followed by rows. putting everything in line will also throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

The likely cause is `d.age*10`. Multiplying a non-numeric string, or `undefined`, results in `NaN`. Try throwing `.each(function(d){console.log(d)})` into the chain, right below `append`, and see if things are what you expect.

You can also try logging the entire `data` and see what it is.

I would also recommend using `.csv` rather than `.txt`. Beyond best practice, it's possible something weird is happening because of that.